# How to store tokens while lexical analysis

Tags: java, c, compiler-construction, token, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to design a compiler, and am at lexical analysis. 
Say I take a simple "Hello World!" program as a file of strings and extract tokens from it.
What is the best way to store these tokens? In a single data structure, or two or more data structures depending on the type of token?

Comment: `List<Token>` is an obvious way to go. Are you asking about the data structure to represent individual tokens, or the data structure allowing iteration over token objects?

Comment: I think i meant individual tokens. Should all the tokens of a program be stored in one data structure or in separate data structures depending on the type of token.
And I reckon i should think in terms of further processing of the tokens during translation and compilation process...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to construct a *parse tree,* not just a list of tokens. I suggest you continue your reading on the subject before you start coding,

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you don't want to store all the tokens, period.

What you want to do is produce the tokens, one at a time, and hand them to the parser.   After the parser inspects the token, the *token* isn't needed anymore.  The parser may copy data from the token and use it to build a node in an AST.  You can arguably get by with a single global token, although that isn't considered to be good practice, and if your language has a preprocessor that operates over token streams this won't work.

Perhaps the question you intended to ask is, how are the AST nodes stored long term?  The answer is that they can be dynamically allocated from the heap, and they are tied together by parent/child links in the AST.  That's enough to track them all reliably.

You might consider indexing the AST nodes according to type.  For most compiling tasks, this is unnecessary.   For some tools, this is useful, as it allows the tool to find various node types in very large trees quickly. YMMV.